# If friction acts on car all time, why is it not accelerating forever?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction, everyday-life

In the first gear, slowly releasing my clutch i push the gas pedal to the maximum torque level, say at 2000 rpm. Now as the engine torque is acting on the wheel, friction helps the car to accelerate.

If i hold the gas pedal at that position, the torque should continuously act on the wheel and the car should increase speed forever. But in reality even if we put the gas pedal at the max.torque rpm range in first gear it speeds up to certain wheel rpm (say 500rpm) and it stays there only. Why?

Comment: -1 Not clear : Are you asking why the engine (and wheel) rpm does not increase indefinitely, to say 1 billion rpm and beyond?

Comment: Firstly, the friction is what is causing the car to slow down, while the drive from the engine is causing the car to speed up. Given that, do you wish to edit the title and ask something different?

Answer (score 2):

Most realistic motors aren't actually built to provide a constant torque as a function of velocity. Rather, as velocity increases, the torque provided by the motor decreases. This is why, for example, transmissions are necessary in cars: most engines have a torque-speed curve that pretty drastically drops off when you move away from the "peak" velocity, so in order to achieve lower speeds at reasonable torques, a gearbox is necessary to exchange these two quantities. DC electric motors have a much better torque-speed curve, which is why most electric cars don't require a transmission. As such, even in a vacuum, you'll have a maximum speed just from the characteristics of your motor.

Once you add in the fact that we don't drive cars in a vacuum, there are actually a few different torques acting on the axles of your car. There is, of course, the torque provided by the motor, but there is also torque from friction between the various components of the axle, and torque that derives from air resistance acting on the front of the car. In particular, the torque from air resistance increases with speed, so you'll eventually reach a point where the torque provided by the motor exactly balances the torque provided by air resistance. This point determines your eventual wheel rpm.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why the whole car does not simply accelerate indefinitely.

If I've understood your question correctly, which is that having set the accelerator to a fixed position in a fixed gear, why does the car (and presumably the engine) not accelerate indefinitely, it is because more and more of the available energy is wasted as speeds increase, until an equilibrium is reached (or until more fuel is added).

Drivetrain and rolling friction is one, noise is another, wind resistance is another.

These all increase until all the available energy of the engine is simply spent on continuing to heat the drivetrain components and the tyres, emitting noise, and perturbing the air through which the car passes.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a car that starts to move or speeds up. It is initially at a lower rpm rate and friction acts on the wheels to increase that rpm rate. As a result you notice that the car starts to speed up. This happens until the tires and the road establish pure rolling.  Once that happens friction doesn't want it to rotate at a faster rate as that would mean relative motion at the point of contact.

Of course Rolling friction will always oppose and slow you down. But since the rpm of the wheels are fixed static friction will always try to maintain pure roll.

(By pure roll I mean no slippage at the point of contact of the ground and wheel)